# When clicking on emulator, there is an infinite clipping sound

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am not talking about something that happens when trying to implement audio in an app. Rather I am talking about the system sound effect when pressing a button on the emulator.

[Here is a recording](https://clyp.it/z04jvvys?token=ce0fd9738594e4f5e2c77a5b391adad7)

This happens on multiple emulators, and it only stops when closing the emulator. Feel free to ask more info about the problem, since I have no idea on what else to include.

Answer (score 1):

This might come from the sound-card of your system; either it's the driver configuration or it's a hardware defect. That's just the dirt which is still in the output buffer, running in a endless loop - most likely because it fails to put new audio samples into that buffer, while nevertheless outputting.

Comment: Wouldn't a sound card issue manifest itself all the time (when hearing music, watching movies, playing games etc)? This sound only comes up in the emulator.

Comment: @Fletcher eg. it that sound-card does not support something alike Mono @ 16KHz. maybe it isn't even failing to fill the buffer with samples, but already failing to switch the sample-rate (or has it locked by the driver). generally wouldn't expect too much from whatever on-board sound card/chip.

Comment: Unfortunately most of what you've said went over my head :(. What should be the next course of action? Reinstalling drivers? Replacing sound card?